# Error: Premature end of script headers: php5

Tags: php, arrays

When I run the following

```
foreach($csv as $row) {
if (!in_array($row[2], $institutions)) {
  $institutions[$row[2]] = $row;
}
```

I get no errors, but when I run this

```
foreach($csv as $row) {
if (!in_array($row[2], $institutions)) {
  $institutions[$row[2]][] = $row;
}
}
```

I get this error

```
Premature end of script headers: php5
```

What is wrong with my code? What I'm trying to do is store all rows from the $csv array into subarrays, with the key being the institution name.

Comment: You opened two `{` and closed one `}`. So you're expecting what?

Comment: Sorry, didn't copy it all in. Its there now, and I still get the error

Comment: Are you sure you have those two examples the right way round? If so, is this the WHOLE code? Is it being `include`'d?